# I use Team Viewer to remotely boot, connect to and use my server PC. How does that work?

Tags: networking, ip, wake-on-lan, teamviewer

Specifically, how does it know where to connect given that I have dynamic IP on that server? Whenever I want to connect to it through any other app, I have to change the IP weekly or so, but TeamViewer always knows that even when the server has been turned off for months, it still knows where to send the wake-up signal.

Answer (score 0):

Teamviewer connections are run through a central swrver (run by Teamviewer the company). Both your cluent and seever are actually cluents using their server - which is a convenient way to punch through NAT and handle dynamic IPs.

Answer (score 0):

The handshaking between the TeamViewer server and client is done via the
TeamViewer website.

If you have set your TeamViewer User Id to be static, this means that
every time your computer starts, it will announce its presence and
IP address to the TeamViewer website servers under the same User Id.

So when your TeamViewer client does connect to the server by this same
User Id, the TeamViewer website can return its IP address and
can facilitate the connection itself, even if both computers are behind
the NAT of their ISP.

Comment: That makes sense, and I understand the concept of TeamViewer server and how they save the ID, but the PC in question stays shut down for months on end, during which time the IP changes weekly. I would then, from another country, login to team viewer and initiate a "Wake Up" signal. Team Viewer will then send that to my PC and connect me to it. If the IP changes, how does Team Viewer know where on the internet to send the signal in the first place? The ID stored from TeamViewer alone is not sufficient for it to know where to send the signal.

Comment: TeamViewer server starts with Windows and contacts the TeamViewer website. I have to guess that it establishes a two-way TCP connection with the website while announcing its UserId. The client also connects to the website, while announcing the UserId of the server. The website then acts as the broker, transmitting messages from one to the other. If server and client are not on NAT, the client can access the server directly, all it needs is the server's IP. I don't know if TeamViewer cam distinguish between the NAT/not-NAT cases and do this optimization.

Answer (score 0):

In layman's terms:

The WOL wake-on-LAN signal is not dependent on the IP address but on the MAC address which usually doesn't change (unless you choose to do so).

To connect to a remote system Teamviewer also doesn't use the IP but the Teamviewer ID of that system. That's why you have to install TeamViewer on the server you want to access as well.

Although it seems like they connect directly to each other from the start, the connection was initially established by a central Teamviewer server on the internet both systems are talking to when establishing a connection. (Note: You can connect within your LAN as well, that works a little different).

Comment: That makes sense, and I understand the concept of TeamViewer server and how they save the ID, but the PC in question stays shut down for months on end, during which time the IP changes weekly. I would then, from another country, login to team viewer and initiate a "Wake Up" signal. Team Viewer will then send that to my PC and connect me to it. If the IP changes, how does Team Viewer know where on the internet to send the signal in the first place? The ID stored from TeamViewer alone is not sufficient for it to know where to send the signal.

Comment: @EduardG as I stated in my question, WOL is not dependent on the IP address but on the MAC address which usually does not change. WOL takes place on layer 2, not layer 3 (there are possibilities to go across layer 3 but that's not what matters here).

Comment: Are you saying then, that I can send a WoL signal to my shutdown PC from anywhere in the world just by using the MAC address?

Comment: No, the MAC address is layer 2 in layman's terms "connected through switches" (LAN only). Implementing WOL through layer 3 is theoretically possible but it requires more than the MAC address.